# Entity Framework4.3 and Unit Testing. Access Violation Exception. Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am using EF4.3, ASP.NET MVC4, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.

Code works fine. I added Unit tests to test Controllers. The Unit tests fails with following exception :

> Access Violation Exception. Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
> at
>   ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(typeof(MyBusinessEntity).Assembly);

I have added [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestProject")]  to my Web project AssemblyInfo.cs

Any suggestions ?

Unit test code:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void GetEntity()
    {
        // Arrange
        MyControllercontroller = new MyController();

        // Act
        var result = controller.GetEntity("737464305") as JsonResult;

        dynamic data = result.Data;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(data);
        Assert.AreEqual("0", data.ProcessStatus);

    }
```

Controller action invokes a Stored Procedure using  Entity Framework4.3 DBContext. The result of SP call is mapped to a Complex Type.  The DBContext code for the SP call is :

```
public virtual ObjectResult<MyEntity> MYSP(string inparam)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(typeof(MyEntity).Assembly);

        var inparamParameter = inparam != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("inparam", inparam) :
            new ObjectParameter("inparam", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<MyEntity>("MYSP", inparamParameter );
    }
```

**In general code works fine. However, 
Access Violation Error is thrown when Controller action is tested using Unit Test. in line ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(typeof(MyEntity).Assembly);**

Comment: give us some lines of context here .

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark, but did you happen to rebuild the project or run the tests while still in debug mode or something? I believe I've seen similar problems in such cases..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. iF ProxyCreationEnabled property of dbContext is set to false, then Unit tests on Controllers or BL methods which inturn invoke SP through Entity Framework are failing with AccessViolation Exception.